# What are the alternatives to play a youtube video in android within the same activity?

Tags: android, video, android-activity, android-intent, youtube

So I have got this application where I need to play a youtube video without calling an intent and in the same activity (not using openyoutube :P), what is the appropriate way(s) to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can embed a `VideoView` within your `Activity` and play the video by giving it some `URL`

See a [demo of using VideoView in Android](http://www.stevenmarkford.com/android-activity-playing-a-video-with-a-videoview/) for more.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I was wondering, how can I play the video using a youtube link like this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l_cJ5fvVhiI within the same activity? should I just put it in the URI?